# Prove that $xo(y^2)=o((x^2 + y^2)^{3/2})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Maybe $$\frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq \frac{1}{2} \quad \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
so
$$ \frac{|xo(y^2)|}{x^2+y^4}\leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{|o(y^2)|}{y^2} \to 0 \text{ if } (x,y) \to (0,0)$$
Therefore we can conclude that $xo(y^2)=o(x^2+y^4)$.

How $o(x^2+y^4)=o((x^2+y^2)^{3/2})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to use polar coordinates: $\frac {xy^{3}} {(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/2}}=\frac {r^{3}\cos \theta \sin^{2}\theta} {r^{3}}$ and $\sin \theta, \cos\theta$ are bounded.